# The clean URL test failed Drupal and Openshift

Tags: uri

I want to clean *URL* in Drupal but get the test failed, and that what I have done in my `httpd.conf` :

```
<Directory "/php/">
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

I have also enabled the `mod_rewrite` but got an error! Any idea?

Comment: just make sure that your drupal root directory is `/php/`. Also trying adding this `.htaccess` file on the drupal root directory. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drupal/drupal/7.x/.htaccess

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to answer your question without knowing your setup, e.g. operating system, drupal version and the location, where your site is hosted (are you trying to view it on localhost or on a remote host?).

If you are running Drupal 7, clean urls should be enabled by default.
So, maybe the following does help:

If the url you are accessing is

```
http://www.your-site.com/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls
```

change it to

```
http://www.your-site.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls
```

... and test again. Does it still fail?

source:  https://drupal.org/node/1572984#comment-6751806